# How to launch Apache Tinkerpop 3.0 gremlin console?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm brand new to this, so trying to figure out how to launch the apache tinkerpop 3.0 gremlin console. I've seen responses that say to unzip & start the console with bin/gremlin.sh. I'm unsure what that means / how to do that (I'm on a mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first step is to go [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/downloads.html) and click on the Gremlin Console button which will take you to a screen with a bunch of mirror links for downloading.  Select one of these and download it.  By default, it will save in the ~/Downloads directory.
2. Open up a Terminal window and go to the Downloads directory (`cd ~/Downloads`)
3. Unzip the newly downloaded Console (`unzip apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.7-bin.zip`)
4. Navigate to the newly unzipped directory (`cd apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.7/`)
5. Run the console (`bin/gremlin.sh`)